# How to get value of nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to get value from a nested dictionary and i am getting string indices must be integers error.

Here is my dictionary

```
dict1 = {'ID': '123', 'Name': 'test', 'VersionId': '123423', 
          'String1': '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}'}
```

I am trying to get the value2 but failing badly. Can anyone shed some light on this.

```
sub_dict = dict1['String1']
res = str(json.loads(sub_dict)) 
print(res['key2'])
```

if i print(res) this prints {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'} but i am unable to get value2

Thanks,

Comment: Don't convert it back to a string with `str`. Just `json.loads` is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just overdid it.

```
sub_dict = dict1['String1']
res = json.loads(sub_dict)
print(res['key2'])
```

You do not need to convert res to a string.